# Remove documents queued by Human-in-the-Loop

Tags: cloud-document-ai

After setting up Human-in-the-Loop and label filters, I noticed I configured the confidence levels too high as lots of correctly processed documents were marked.

I've since lowered the confidence thresholds and now fewer documents get marked, but I'd like to remove the earlier documents from the queue to focus our labelling efforts on the most problematic documents.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you try using unassign from tasks option in the Assignments dashboard? You can refer to this [document](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/docai-hitl#4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment from [Prajna Rai T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15747414/prajna-rai-t)

You should be able to remove documents from the labeling queue by using the Labeling Manager console to unassign documents for review.

Here's the main documentation for the label manager console:

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/hitl/manage-labeling-tasks

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/hitl/lm-console